Why do muslims believe their sins can paid for by the unbeliever? The unbelievers blood is sinful. God is perfect. Is this not mocking God?
God is perfect therefore the sacrifice must be perfect as God is a perfect and righteous Judge and the sin must be paid for perfectly or the God in question is not a God because God has no blemish, stain or mark and to stand before him in judgment without absolute assurance of sin being perfectly dealt with would be very dangerous and the most serious eternal risk any person would and can ever take. For example : Our sin is not judged but the actual person who is a sinner, the sins committed are a by-product of being a sinner therefore we cannot seperate the sins from the sinner. The sin can be forgiven but the sinner remains a sinner and to stand before a perfect God would be like placing petrol covered rag in front of a blazing pure and perfect eternal clean and pure fire. Surely God perfect standard is to be kept, never would God who is perfect lower his perfect standard to accomodate mere sinners as this would be God becoming less than who he is - perfect. God must and cannot compromise in the slightest or all sinners by nature would behave in every evil way excusing all types of evils and transgressions based on faulty scales of judgment and justice then take a huge risk going to judgment before the most righteous and pure living God. This is a major problem for all men whatever religion, ideology or belief they adhere to. God must be perfectly satisfied based upon who he actually really is , a perfect righteous judge who is God.

Your idea of a "perfect God" is based on your desires. One of the attributes of God is also being the lord of mercy and in effect, his mercy being more common than his wrath. Secondly, your idea of his justice is also based on human perceptions while him being just is a pre-eternal attribute of his that was before any creation and before time. He was just, the creator, the merciful, before he created us and all of creation. God would be just no matter what judgment he gives regarding his creation, which is his own. 1/2.

His attribute of justice would not have any effect on it even if he were to throw every pious person in hell and give heaven to the worse kind of sinners. His justice is beyond our worldly perceptions of what is just and what is unjust. And whatever his judgment is, it is always is just. He created you with the ability to sin, and he is the only one who can forgive the sins. And yes, someone whose sins are forgiven is like someone who didn't commit them in the first place. Every person, despite their sins, that goes to heaven will be purified and cleansed from them.

https://islamqa.org/shafii/darul-iftaa-jordan/228871/sins-and-their-means-of-forgiveness/

Allah knows best and may he forgive me for any mistake I made in those comments, Aameen.

And let me clarify that when I say "in effect" I mean with regards to his creation. https://islamqa.org/hanafi/hadithanswers/120141/my-mercy-prevails-over-my-wrath/ https://seekersguidance.org/answers/islamic-belief/why-is-allah-merciful/ Also, the example I gave of pious in hell and evil in heaven is just a hypothetical example. We all know that Allah will give heaven to whoever he wills by his mercy but the primary criteria on the judgment day would be 1) Believing in Allah and what he ordered to believe in properly. 2) Doing good deeds and having scale heavier than that of bad deeds.

No person is admitted into heaven by their own good deeds. Rather, it is the endless mercy of God that we depend on and that we are admitted into heaven by.

Abu Huraira reported Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) as saying:
None amongst you would attain salvation purely because of his deeds. A person said: Allah's Messenger, even you? Thereupon he said: Yes, not even I except that Allah wraps me in Mercy, but you should act with moderation. This hadith has been transmitted on the authority of Bukair b. al-Ashajj with a slight variation of wording.


Narrated `Aisha:
The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "Do good deeds properly, sincerely and moderately, and receive good news because one's good deeds will not make him enter Paradise." They asked, "Even you, O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)?" He said, "Even I, unless and until Allah bestows His pardon and Mercy on me."

And the disbeliever is not admitted into Paradise.

Assalamoalikum, I appreciate the answer, however, I believe that part you say "not even Prophet Muhammad (SAW)" could be sufficiently removed, it adds nothing of value. I am aware that what the hadith says is the truth, but in ahl as sunnah, there is an emphasis on the respect of the Prophet PBUH and the pious predecessors and avoiding to mention anything that may cause their status to show similar to that of a normal person.

Some of the high esteemed scholars would even go as far as to prevent their students from saying, "There was dirt on the clothes of the Prophet PBUH" and would have them say, "Some dirt got the blessing of touching the clothes of the beloved servant of Allah, sallahu 'alayhi wasallam.". Quoting hadith, is once again, completely fine and should be done precisely, but when you mention your own statement from them, it should be done in a manner that maintains and mentions the honor and respect of the Prophet PBUH and the pious predecessors.

@SyedM.Sannan wa alaykum assalam wa rahmatullah. I have removed it.

May Allah bless you, guide you towards his blessings, and increase you in knowledge and piety, and goodness in the world and in the hereafter, Allahumma Aameen.

Justice is based on law or laws therefore the law must be satisfied. A law not satisfied is neither justice or law. Law demands payment or there is no law, just lawlessness, a shadow or a flexible perception which can be used or abused depending on the individual. The problem remains, unless there is sufficient payment and the satisfying of the law which as Gods standard must be perfect i maintain the eternal danger of having no absolute assurance of security before God and absolutely before going to judgment, what a terrible risk and assumption to make.

May i also reply to the comment regarding Gods eternal attribute from eternity past in relation to his justice. Gods justice is not apart from him neither can it be. Gods justice is the very nature of God himself, not an attribute as we understand. Man thinks in terms of seperation,God is just, is pure, is perfect righteousness therefore my desires and insight regarding the perfection of God always falls short. God by nature is absolute justice and his standard of justice must be a crystal clear reflection of him. How mercy is given must be according to a perfect sacrifice or no assurance.

@Scythiannomad. You come here with your subjective Christian perception of God and claim that Islam mocks it while portraying it as something objective. You need to understand that your belief of what God's justice is does not align with Islam, neither does your belief of his mercy, punishment, wrath, compassion, etc. Your anthropomorphize God way too much for Islam to consider it to have any sense and then you come here and expect us to debate you with false premise.

@Scythiannomad. So the brief answer to your question "Is this not mocking God?" is no, because our concept of his justice is distinctly different from yours. We disagree on the main premise so there can't be a fruitful discussion out of this.

@Scythiannomad. You claim that every sinner would go to hell if God were to judge them, while we believe that God's judgment is not bound by our human perceptions of it. God can throw every pious man, even someone who never sinned in his life, into hell, and give heaven to Satan, and God would still be just because his justice is absolute and is not bound by our perception of it. It is only that Allah decided to let us know that he will judge us by our correctness of belief in him and what he ordered to believe and by our actions (good vs bad deeds).

@Scythiannomad. And even after that, there is intercession of the Prophet PBUH, where he will ask Allah to forgive the sinful Muslims and Allah will forgive them. AND EVEN AFTER THAT, Allah is not bound by what he told us. We know for certain he will do those things because he fulfills his promise, but he is still not bounded in any way whatsoever. You imagine the nature of God on your own and bound him by it by insinuating that he must throw every sinner in hell, while we believe that we cannot comprehend the nature of God, and that he does what he wills and is not questioned while we are.

@Scythiannomad. Our only understanding of Allah are based strictly on what the scripture says. Our understanding of his speech, justice, mercy, attribute of being the creator, etc. are all strictly based on what the scripture says and we do not insinuate beyond that and we do not claim that we can comprehend the very nature of God. That is a claim of Christians who think that they have the mind to predict what judgment God would make in X circumstances, while we do not bind God with such.

@Scythiannomad. Moreover, after all the things I mentioned, there may be other elements to his judgment on the day of reckoning that Allah has not revealed to us. He can forgive someone even without judgment and throw someone in hell without it, and would still be just. He is just no matter what he does, and we can't always comprehend. I think I have made my point very clear now. Our God and your idea of God are so fundamentally different that you believe that God lives in the heaven, while we believe that the heaven is a creation of God and that he is transcendent beyond all creation.

@Scythiannomad. And as this answer mentions, even after all those elements, anyone who is forgiven and sent to heaven is sent by God's mercy and not his/her actions. And when I say you "bound God" and we do not, I mean you bound him in/with your perception. Most obviously, whatever you and I think of God has no effect on who he really is and no one can bind him in any way whatsoever.

Allah knows best and may he forgive me for any mistake I made in those comments, Aameen.

I came from nowhere, I raised a crucial pont regarding justice. Yours or our perception of justice is eternally irrelevant as God will judge according to Himself. He doesnt adjust justice to accomodate any man. Mercy requires a price, a setting right, straight. We do not have the currency required. When men are trapped by there own sin and unbalanced sense of justice it has been know to make most claustrophobic and then come out fighting only entangling themselves deeper in condemnation based on fear. Judgment is certain. No offence was meant. Truth in context is King.

From the nature of your arguments, I am going to assume that you are Christian, and phrase the rest of my answer accordingly. If you're not, I apologize, but the answer should remain applicable regardless.
What you're describing is not any sort of mainstream Islamic belief; the concept of blood being an atonement for sin comes from the Mosaic Law. Despite the fact that there are similarities between that and Islamic laws, and the fact that both come from Allah, the Mosaic Law was explicitly given to the nation of Israel and was never claimed to apply to anyone else.
I assume that you are basing this belief on the hadith of the prophet where he is reported to have said "When it will be the Day of Resurrection Allah would deliver to every Muslim a Jew or a Christian and say: That is your rescue from Hell-Fire."; while this hadith is considered authentic, the interpretation of this being some sort of blood sacrifice to atone for sins is strange and not in accordance with Islamic teachings, where "every soul earns not except against itself, and no bearer of burdens will bear the burden of another.". This hadith was discussed in detail in a related question, and I will not elaborate on it here.
Similar to Christianity, Islam acknowledges that men are are weak and prone to sin. "Indeed, the soul is a persistent enjoiner of evil, except those upon which my Lord has mercy." Allah created us and knows best our weaknesses, and it is only through His Mercy that any of us have a chance of entering Heaven.
"And if Allah were to impose blame on the people for what they have earned, He would not leave upon the earth any creature", but despite our weaknesses we continue to be tested in the world rather than condemned immediately. According to hadith reports, "All the sons of Adam are sinners, but the best of sinners are those who repent often."
Allah is Most Just, so we will be held to account for all that our souls have earned. However, Allah is also Most Merciful, and there are hadith reports that His Mercy will prevail over His Wrath. Justice and Mercy are not incompatible; if my neighbour offends me and I forgive him, that is not unjust, that is my right and prerogative as the one who was offended. Similarly, if any man sins against Allah, it is His right and His prerogative to forgive whosoever He chooses.
In the Bible, in the Torah, Allah gave the Children of Israel the laws of sacrifice: "For the life of a creature is in the blood, and I have given it to you to make atonement for yourselves on the altar; it is the blood that makes atonement for one’s life." This is also Allah's Mercy on the Children of Israel: As above, He knows that they are weak because all mankind is weak. He knows that they will sin, and grants them the ritual to "earn" forgiveness.
There isn't some inherently magical property of blood that forces Allah to forgive them, that sort of onus would not be befitting of His Majesty. He is bound by His Law because He is Most Just, and the rituals He commands are good because He is Good, but what He is judging is our piety, not our ability to follow ritual instructions from a textbook. "Their meat will not reach Allah , nor will their blood, but what reaches Him is piety from you."
And as I mentioned above, that law was given to the Children of Israel, and it is in that context that the sacrifice of Christ Jesus needs to be understood. Islam is not a "sequel" to Judaism: We do not follow the Mosaic Law, and as such the concept of blood atonement for sin was never part of our law, just as it was never binding on anyone outside of the Nation of Israel. Allah has given us our own rituals and our own methods for absolving ourselves of sin, but even these don't preclude Allah from forgiving whosoever He pleases, as befits His Majesty.
And most importantly, whether we're forgiven or not, we are not perfect. Allah is Perfect, but if perfection is needed to stand in His presence, we will never be able to attain that because we can never be anything more than one of His creations. We submit to Allah because we recognize His Majesty, and acknowledge that we can accomplish nothing if He withholds it, not because we expect to attain equal status to Him.

You have quoted sections and parts of the Torah in your own words and cherry picked parts and failed to mention the whole part of the law in context. For example you rightly mention Adam, all in Adam is all mankind because this was the entering of seperation and corruption. This fall was a cataclysm, total death not partial death which entered man, all men dead to God completely because a seed replicates after its own kind throughout human generations seperating from God rejecting God now out of revelation and right relationship barred from the tree of life by a sword ( judgment).

The serpent desires to be god, replace God first by getting Adam man to consume his lie and knowing that doing so will bring in total seperation. This worked, was effective, a total seperation, now under the tree of the knowledge of good and evil, two branches of the same tree leading to death. Very cunning but effective and absolutely deceptive and clever. An intelligence based on pride, rebellion, rejection and now trapped in knowledge based system with the serpent a god over mans fall.

There were two trees, the Tree of life and the serpent tree the main focus regarding God, the serpent and man. Man now barred from the tree of life also with fruit and seed - Gods living word they could have had access to till they ate from the forbidden tree. Sin entered and Adam is darkened to God, no light, no revelation now stuck and trapped in knowledge, seperated and barred from tree of life by a fiery sword which indicates judgment thus man can not have Gods life with mere knowledge of good and evil. They need a sacrifice. God provides the first sacrifice, covers them with skin.

@Scythiannomad. You were asking for an Islamic perspective, that is what I provided. I am not interested in arguing Christian theology with you.

An animal skin. He then spells out the consequences of the sin and rebellion which is toil, labour, working under the dictate of the serpent tree is which we see today still, all men everywhere. Gods rolls out the salvation and it is not by knowledge or labour or human effort whether by pious religious activity, thought or belief but by sacrifice simply because the fall was absolute and total death needing a perfect solution, sacrifice by God not man because man is dead in sin unable to reach God needing rescued now from self, himself, now a sinner.

My point in beggining was justice and i thank you for you viewpoint contribution. We never stop seeking truth, the truth can only do one thing and that is set you free. May God bless you and surround you with truth, love peace and eternal life now and forever.
